# Apache Poi Word Table, information about the Alt Text

Tags: apache, ms-word, apache-poi

How to get the Alt Text from a Table in Word, e.g. Title or Description.
All the Information, that I found had the context, Text, Width, Style etc. to read or modify.

My goal is to identify certain Tables in a Template, so I can modify them.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make some assumptions here. First that you are talking about the `docx` format, and second that by "Alt Text" you mean a caption.

A caption is just a paragraph that either precedes, or follows a table. It will have a style of `Caption`, a run with some text like *Table*, and probably includes a simple field `SEQ Table`. That would be the default Table caption, but it could be just a run with a name like *Department Heads*. The key is the style name. Word uses standard style names to calculate other things as well such as `TOC`.

**Note:** in Word, you cannot modify a caption by selecting a table, and clicking a menu option. It isn't really linked in any meaningful way. You have to modify the paragraph.

So to find a caption, you need to look in the Document elements list `XWPFDocument.getBodyElements()`, and find each paragraph with a style of `Caption`. Once you have found the one you want, then you can either look at the element immediately above or below to find the table. Your search will be easier if you can know that captions are all above or all below the tables.

So to retrieve the table following a specific named caption I would try something like this:

```
public XWPFTable FindTable(String name) {
    boolean foundTable = false;
    XWPFParagraph p;
    for (IBodyElement elem : doc.getBodyElements()) {
        switch (elem.getElementType()) {
        case PARAGRAPH:
            foundTable = false;
            p = (XWPFParagraph) elem;
            if (p.getStyle() == "Caption" && p.getText() == name) {
                foundTable = true;
            }
            break;
        case TABLE:
            if (foundTable) {
                return (XWPFTable) elem;
            }
            break;
        case CONTENTCONTROL:
            foundTable = false;
            break;
        default:
            foundTable = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for your comprehensive answer. With "Alt Text" i mean, the  entry of a table properties in word. If you click with the right mouse button on an table, and you choose table properties, and in the dialog the last tab, that means Alt Text. That was it, was i mean. But your solution is also possible for me. Thnx.

Comment: Ok, I see the issue. POI uses the 2006 spec. `Alt Text` is part of the tblCaption element of `table properties (tblPr)`. That is not present in the 2006 spec, and therefore is not present in the ooxml schema that we use. If you need the `Alt Text`, you may still be able to get at it by navigating through the XML yourself, but POI will not help you do that directly. If you can use the table caption, that will be your best bet. Otherwise you will need to create a method to retrieve the value of the `tblCaption` node in the XML.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your Information are very helpfull.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, either upvote, or mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In Word you can set the table caption to something unique, and then get the table in xml:

```
String tableXML = mytable.getCTTbl();
```

To extract the table caption:

```
String[] xml = tableXML.split(System.lineSeparator());
String caption = null;
for (String x : xml)
{
    if (x.contains("w:tblCaption"))
    {
        caption = x.split("w:val=")[1].replace("/>", "");
        caption = caption.replace("\"", "");
    }
}
```